# How do you properly check if filename exist and generate a suffix before writing it to the directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that writes a file to a directory:

```
response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullPath))
```

But before that I want to check if the path already exist, and if so, add a suffix, e.g. `file_1.txt` (and if that exist, create `file_2.txt` instead...etc):

```
// Check if the path already exist
let fullPath = "C:/test/file.txt"
let dir = "C:/test/"
let fileName = "file" 
let fileExt = ".txt"

if (fs.existsSync(fullPath)) {
  // I tried using a while loop but I end up making it too complicated
  ...
}


// Write file to disk
response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destinationPath))
```

### Question

How do I properly / efficiently do that?

Comment: Same thing as what? I deleted my comment when I saw that. Please add the "too complicated" code that you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while` loop is the correct way.

```
// Check if the path already exist
let fullPath = "C:/test/file.txt"
let dir = "C:/test/"
let fileName = "file" 
let fileExt = ".txt"
let num = 0;

while (fs.existsSync(fullPath)) {
  fullPath = `${dir}${fileName}_${num++}${fileExt}`;
}
```

After this, `fullPath` contains the first nonexistent file.

Note that there's a potential race condition. Some other process could create the file after your loop finishes.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly the simplistic solution I've been looking for!

Comment: It would be best if your question showed the code that didn't work.

Comment: I didn't include it because it was really over complicated (like 4 variables and 2 more if conditions). Yeah, I guess you shouldn't write code when you're tired...

Answer (score 2):

If all of your file names are named the same thing + "_#".txt, I think the most (one of the most) efficient ways to check that would be something along the lines of:

Get all files from the directory

```
var files = [];
fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    files.push(file);
  });
})
```

You would then sort the array (could be expensive if a lot of files)... then last record would be the highest number which you can easily extract.

Another thing you could do is find the file which has the latest creation date using similar approach using the Stats class from FS.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution! Though it wouldn't work in my case because some folders contain thousands of files

Comment: In your solution, you don't actually have to extract any numbers from the filenames afterwards, I think you could just check if `files.include(fullPath)`

Comment: I don't see how it would't work. If your sequence of files is breaking then a while loop as Barmar said is the most effective, as it will stop when it finds an empty sequence, also doesn't use the same amount of resources. You need to extract the number in my solution, I'm not incrementing any counters, so you would need to get the number from the last file to create your filename... or just add a counter. It's just a quick answer I thought of. My solution will also be more resource friendly if you're performing this action numerous times.

Answer (score 1):

Get all files from the directory and sort them:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(pathName)
    .map(function(v) { 
      return { name:v}; 
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return a.nam > b.name; })
    .map(function(v) { return v.name; });
```

And by latest creation date.

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(dir)
     .map(function(v) { 
         return { name:v,
           time:fs.statSync(dir + v).mtime.getTime()
        }; 
     })
     .sort(function(a, b) { return a.time - b.time; })
     .map(function(v) { return v.name; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a very simplistic solution, this seems unnecessary  complicated. Thank you though for a solution

Comment: Where does this return the name of the new file?

Comment: This will return all files name in Array and then sort them and create a new name based on that. Loads of files may be some expensive.